# MS-Access query does not correctly interpret DBNull.Value using OLEDB.NET

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I am connecting to a MS-Access 2007 database using VB 2010 and OLEDB. Conducting the following test seems to suggest that MS-Access does not interpret DBNull.Value correctly when sent as a parameter from OLEDB:

(The Hospital table contains 1 row with the "LatLong" column set to null)

```
Dim cnt = Common.GetScalar(axsCon, "SELECT Count(*) FROM Hospitals WHERE LatLong = @LL ", _
                New String() {"LL"},
                New Object() {DBNull.Value})
```

This query returns cnt = 0

However:
cnt = Common.GetScalar(axsCon, "SELECT Count(*) FROM Hospitals WHERE LatLong IS NULL ")

returns cnt = 1

Any ideas are appreciated.

p.s.:
Common.GetScalar looks like:

```
Public Shared Function GetScalar( _
    ByRef OleCon As OleDbConnection, _
    ByRef SQL As String, _
    Optional ByRef Params() As String = Nothing, _
    Optional ByRef Vals() As Object = Nothing, _
    Optional IsQuery As Boolean = False) As Object
    Try
        Dim oleCmd As OleDbCommand = OleCon.CreateCommand
        oleCmd.CommandType = IIf(IsQuery, CommandType.StoredProcedure, CommandType.Text)
        oleCmd.CommandText = SQL
        If Not Params Is Nothing Then
            Dim pInx As Int16
            For pInx = 0 To Params.Count - 1
                oleCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(Params(pInx), Vals(pInx))
            Next
        End If
        Return oleCmd.ExecuteScalar()
    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw New Exception(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Function
```

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
"SELECT Count(*) FROM Hospitals WHERE LatLong = @LL"
```

to

"SELECT Count(*) 
FROM Hospitals 
WHERE 1= 
    CASE 
        WHEN @LL IS null AND LatLong IS null THEN 1 
        WHEN LatLong = @LL THEN 1 
    END"

This will then check for null or matching value.  Nulls can be very very tricky.

Answer (score 0):

Your GetScalar will run the query:

`SELECT Count(*) FROM Hospitals WHERE LatLong = NULL`

but you want

`SELECT Count(*) FROM Hospitals WHERE LatLong IS NULL`

You need to switch out the `=` for `IS` if you're comparing to null.

Comment: The OP was trying to do this with parameters.

Comment: That's not what it looked like to me. They are inserting the Null as a parameter, but the `=` is hard-coded into the literal SQL string.